# How to detect current instance

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to know if there is a way to detect on which instance my app is running (development, staging or production) with react-native ? I found nothing on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if you are in development or not using thr global constant: ´ **DEV** ´ (With 2 underscores in each side, this text editor will hide underscores for some reason), it will return true if in development mode, false otherwise.

Example:

```
if(__DEV__){
  console.log("Development mode enabled");
}else{
  console.log("Development mode disabled");
}
```